# how do I access model fields individually?

Tags: python, django, model

suppose I have this model:

```
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)  
datetime_from = models.DateTimeField('time')

model = MyModel
def read(self, request, id=0):
    if not id:
        id = 0        
 MyModel.object 
    mmodel = MyModel.objects.filter(id__gt=id)
    return mmodel
```

My question is, how do I possible get the model fields individually, because I need to validate the datetime_from before I have to output the data on json format

Comment: Please check your code before posting. What is that `MyModel.object` line doing there?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create an `id` column yourself. The `read` method is not necessary, either. Just say

```
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
    datetime_from = models.DateTimeField('time')
```

You can then query the table like so

```
>>> obj = MyModel.objects.get(id=<target id here>)
>>> date = obj.datetime_from
etc.
```